# How to set the title of a struts jquery dialog tag dynamically through jquery/java script?

Tags: jquery-ui, struts2

How to set the title attribute of a struts2 jquery tag dynamically using jquery.
Here is my code

script that sets the title of the dialog tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function grid_click()
{
    $.ajax({
          url: 'myAction',
          success: function(data) {
          solution.innerHTML =data;

          $("dialog#solution").title("Myticket");//fails to execute

          }
        });

    $('#solution').dialog('open');      
}  
</script>
```

The dialog tag without the title attribute.

```
    <sj:dialog id="solution"  
    resizable="false" 
    autoOpen="false" 
    openTopics="openSolution"  
    cssClass="solutionPopup"
    modal="true" 
        overlayColor="#903" 
        overlayOpacity="0.8" 
        position="['center','top']"
        width="830"
        height="600"
        cssStyle="overflow: hidden;"

    >
</sj:dialog>
```

When I call the dialog display, title is empty while rendering.. Please help me to fix this or other alternative.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('dialog#solution').dialog('option', 'title', 'MyTicket');
$('dialog#solution').dialog('open');
```

Comment: Hi dude, I tried the following and got correct output what I expected. $('#solution').dialog('option', 'title', 'MyTicket');